# JQuery using .html to past ajax data in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a problem with pasting some html into a div. I think I know what I'm doing wrong but I cannot find a solution to this. I have an empty div called "allbrands". This div is getting filled with data from an POST ajax call after a button has been clicked. I have made a loop that loops through the data, but it replaces the html constantly. So how can i paste this html table without replacing everytime the content?

My div:

```
<div id="allbrands">

</div>
```

My Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function()
    {
        $('[name="getbrands"]').click(function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/brands/all',
                success: function (data)
                {
                       for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                           $('#allbrands').html('<h6>' + data[i] + '</h6><hr>');
                       }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The data is filled like this: 
[image]

Comment: Use the jquery append function instead of the html function (.html is going to replace everything in the div) http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$('#allbrands').html('<h6>' + data[i] + '</h6><hr>');
```

to

```
$('#allbrands').append('<h6>' + data[i] + '</h6><hr>');
```

and try again.

**Explanation:** `html()` replace the old content by adding new one, `append()` retain old one and append new as well.

Comment: Sounds great :) 
happy coding

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your loop. You are overriding the div's value on each iteration.
You need to append the value rather than override it:

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('#allbrands').append('<h6>' + data[i] + '</h6><hr>');
 }
```

Comment: You voted "No action required" on a spam/troll question. It was still caught in the end by others, downvoted to -22, and then deleted by spam flags by others. Since the "First Posts" queue only requires a single reviewer (you) to dismiss as "No action required", the question was "okay-ed" by you and taken out of the queue when it should have been closed or flagged (that would have allowed other users in the queue to take immedate action as well).

Comment: This discussion doesnt belong here. Let's remove it if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below link for more information

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Also  add the

```
$("#allbrands").append();
```